# Shorter version of Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "subdirectory/**/*.rb")]?

Tags: ruby

This is a bit of a micro question, but every time I create a gem and need to load all the files under a subdirectory for some sort of reflective purpose (or just a quick and dirty pre-load), I ask myself "surely there has to be a cleaner way?", in reference to this common pattern:

```
Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "subdirectory/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

The need to call `File.dirname` on `__FILE__` that makes it needlessly verbose.  You can't really use a relative path inside a gem, since you have no idea where you're being loaded from.

Comment: interpolate the directory name instead of calling `File.join`

Comment: Heh, I guess that works :)  File.join does some stuff for Windows, but given that ruby will load files using `/` regardless, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788550/is-there-a-shorter-way-to-require-a-file-in-the-same-directory-in-ruby and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735073/best-way-to-require-all-files-from-a-directory-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which rube do you use? With ruby 1.9 you can use `require_relative`.

```
require_relative 'subdirectory/file1.rb'
require_relative 'subdirectory/file2.rb'
#...
```

But you must know the files. `require_relative` will not work with *all files in subdirectory*. But I would not recommend to use such a generic read in a gem. You should know what you load.

If you really want it, you may use something like this:

```
Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__)){
  Dir["**/*.rb"].each { |f| 
    require_relative f
  }
}
```

With ruby 1.8 this should work:

```
Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__)){
  Dir["./**/*.rb"].each { |f| 
    require f
  }
}
```

---

Regarding *File.join does some stuff for Windows*: File.join builds the Path, so the OS may use it. In unix the path separator is `/`, in windows `\`. But as you already wrote: ruby understands `/`, so it doesn't matter in windows. But what happens if you work with Classic Mac OS? There it is a `:` (see [Wikipedia Path_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)). So it is better to use join, (or you use my Dir.chdir variant)

Comment: Great answer. I didn't know about require_relative, thanks!  I'm using ruby 1.9 and tbh, not concerned with supporting 1.8 in gems I write... I think supporting old versions of languages just slows down the development of the language in the longer term ;)