# Get path to Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm actually writing my own Ruby gem. It is yet not packed and under development.

How can I get the path to the files within the Gem and how can I get the path from where the gem is called from?

Comment: thanks andrew for making my use of the english language better :)

Comment: For what do you need it? If you need a [way to require a file located in the same directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788550/is-there-a-shorter-way-to-require-a-file-in-the-same-directory-in-ruby/7862107#7862107) then you may find easier ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get path where gem is:

```
File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..'))
```

Where gem is called from:

```
current_dir = Dir.pwd
```